# Delayed ExecutorService with manual start

Tags: java, android, executorservice, runnable, completable-future

I have a simple ExecutorService (via `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`) that I use to submit `Runnable`s to. However, I would like to queue up these Runnables and only let the ExecutorService execute them once I manually notify it (only once).

N.B. I am not trying to make this into a synchronous procedure -- I merely want to control when the execution of the submitted Runnables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with [completable-future](/questions/tagged/completable-future), I suppose, you are thinking into the following direction:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

CompletableFuture<Void> trigger = new CompletableFuture<>();

// submit your jobs
trigger.thenRunAsync(aRunnable, es);
trigger.thenRunAsync(anotherRunnable, es);
trigger.thenRunAsync(yetAnotherRunnable, es);

// and later-on
trigger.complete(null);
// now all Runnables will get submitted and executed


// you can use the same construct even after trigger point
// then, the runnable will get submitted immediately

trigger.thenRunAsync(aRunnable, es);

// finally
es.shutdown();
```

But note that this will not maintain the submission order as all actions were modeled as only depending on the trigger. If you need to keep the order, you may use something like

```
CompletableFuture<Void> trigger = new CompletableFuture<>();
CompletableFuture<Void> order = trigger;

// submit your jobs
order = order.thenRunAsync(aRunnable, es);
order = order.thenRunAsync(anotherRunnable, es);
order = order.thenRunAsync(yetAnotherRunnable, es);

// and later-on
trigger.complete(null);
```

Since this will submit the next job only when the previous has been completed you have to be careful regarding the time of shutting down the `ExecutorService`. But you can use `order.join()` to wait for the completion of all jobs.

Further, care must be taken when different threads may submit jobs this way, as then, the update of the `order` variable must be done in a threadsafe manner.

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to do with `invokeAll()`.  You need to create a `Collection` of `Callable`s:

```java
        List<Callable<?>> tasks = ...;
                                   
        executor.invokeAll(tasks);
}
```

`invokeAll()` waits until all `Callable`s complete.